# Keeping ponly the row-wise maximum of a tensor and setting to zero all the other entries

Tags: pytorch

Given a tensor like this

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 1.0534, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 1.0944, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [1.2780, 1.5430, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [1.1799, 1.2002, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]
```

I want to transform it by keeping only the maximum element for each row, and setting all the others to 0. I was trying to play around with `torch.argmax(tensor, dim=1)` but not sure that is going to help. So the desired output in this case would be

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 1.0534, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 1.0944, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 1.5430, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 1.2002, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work:

```
a = torch.randn((8, 7))
max_a, ids = torch.max(a, 1, keepdim=True)
b = torch.zeros_like(a)     # result tensor
b.scatter_(1, ids, max_a)   # set max values on idx indices
```